# how to invoke a trigger in sql management studio every time there is an insert/update/delete

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm sending a demo trigger

```
"
CREATE TRIGGER MyTestTrigger
   ON  dbo.tblCursor
   AFTER INSERT
AS 

Declare @ino int
set @ino=1

WHILE (@ino<(select count(*) from tblcursor where ExpieryDate>getdate()))
BEGIN
    UPDATE  tblCursor
    SET IsActive = 'true'
    WHERE ExpieryDate>getdate()
set @ino=@ino+1
END

select * from tblcursor
```

"
In my original trigger I'm using CURSOR  instead of Select Command ,now again i'm telling a problem
n my prblm is that I just want to invoked that trigger 'MyTestTrigger'  object without performing any Commands(Insert,Update,Delete)
whenever sql server management studio starts it's automatically invoked that trigger.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can't invoke a trigger since they act upon events such as inserts/deletes/updates. If you want to invoke your statements, convert them to a stored procedure.

Besides, your `MyTestTrigger` is an `AFTER INSERT` trigger, which means that unless you insert something; nothing will happen.

As far as invoking your statements when you start Visual Studio, create a command wrapper that first executes your SQL statements and then starts Visual Studio.